# smtp on vagrant box, connection times out

Tags: smtp, vagrant

I have a vagrant box running ubuntu 11.10 and a PHP script that uses swiftmailer to send email.  My mail provider is SES, although I've replicated the issue with Mailgun and sendgrid as well.

My issue is that when I attempt to send mail on the vagrantbox I get "Connection to tcp://email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:465 Timed Out".  However when I run the exact same script from the host machine, it works fine.

Here's ifconfig on my vagrant box:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:6e:cd:85  
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe6e:cd85/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:272963 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:138823 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:375217285 (375.2 MB)  TX bytes:8245622 (8.2 MB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:50:d1:0c  
          inet addr:192.168.33.10  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe50:d10c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:468 (468.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:181 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:181 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:18416 (18.4 KB)  TX bytes:18416 (18.4 KB)
```

eth1 is a host only network interface with a static ip.

**UPDATE:** This appears to be a problem with swiftmailer. I had different copies of it between my host and guest boxes. I updated my host box, and now I'm getting the same issue where the connection times out.

Answer (score 1):

check whether port is accessible from virtual host and if not, make it accessible using port forwarding or open port in firewall.

Comment: I don't think that's the issue, as I can execute the following on the vagrant box: openssl s_client -crlf -quiet -connect email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:465 and can EHLO and receive code 250 successfully.

Comment: This appears to be a problem with swiftmailer.  I had different copies of it between my host and guest boxes.  I updated my host box, and now I'm getting the same issue where the connection times out.

Comment: This seems to be unrelated to my box setup.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15093702/swiftmailer-completely-broken-for-smtp